# How to kill proccess that spawns several java programs that each take a port

Tags: java, kill

I have a program .sh that spawns several child proces like so:

```
javac *.java
rmiregistry 3300 & 
sleep 5
java Node 3300 3001 1 &
sleep 1
java Node 3300 3002 1 &
sleep 1
java Node 3300 3003 1 &
sleep 1
java Node 3300 3004 1 &
sleep 1
java Node 3300 3005 1 &
```

Now When I run this in a terminal screen I would like to be able to do something like ctr-c to stop this. However when I do it does not release the ports taken by the Nodes. Is there any way to make sure that when I ctr-c the ports are unbound or is there a shortkey that also frees up the ports used by the child processes? Or do I have to use a separate kill command?  Also note that the nodes can and do launch multiple threads themselves (from within java).

Comment: Can you modify the script?

Comment: I'am free to modify the script.

Answer (score 0):

The way to kill all the jobs launched by a process is to use the process group ID (pgid). The simplest way to see that it to launch your script in the background:

```
$ launch_java.sh &
[1] 25649
```

The number printed above is the PID of the `launch_java.sh` which is also the group ID since that launches the rest. Alternatively, you can find it through `ps`:

```
$ ps -a -o pgid,command | grep java
25649 java Node 3300 3002 1
```

The 1st field is the pgid. Once you have that, you can use `kill` to kill it and all its children:

```
kill -TERM -25649
```

As explained in `man kill`:

```
          -n     where n is larger than 1.  All processes in process group
                 n are signaled.  When an argument of  the  form  '-n'  is
                 given,  and it is meant to denote a process group, either
                 a signal must be specified first, or the argument must be
                 preceded  by a '--' option, otherwise it will be taken as
                 the signal to send.
```

Answer (score -1):

use `ps -aef` or `ps -aux` command to find PID of  parent of children and kill it by `kill -9 PID` .

Comment: 1) Do not use `-9` unless absolutely necessary, that can leave your system in a dirty state. 2) Killing the parent won't kill the children if they've been launched in the background as shown in the OP's example.

Comment: @terdon SOMETIMES killing parent won't kill children.You can try it on apache !

Comment: Yes, sometimes. Specifically if they've been launched in the background as is the case here.